# Escondendo elemento dentro de um menu

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3

Tenho um menu assim..

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger vermDigifred btn-xs dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="dropdown"> </button>                                           

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li  ><a id="btnExcluirRegistro" ng-click="excluirDistritos(dis)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Excluir registro</a></li>
        <li > <a id="btnAlterarRegistro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAlterarDistrito" ng-click="alterarDistritos(dis)" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Alterar registro</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Quero fazer uma função em Js para esconder a tag `a` se, por exemplo,  excluir =1

Comment: O que seria `excluir`? Uma variável no JavaScript? E o que já tentou fazer?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, o excluir é uma variavel JavaScript que recebe um valor que pode ser 0 ou 1, então se for 1 eu gostaria que aquela  tag ficasse escondida

Comment: As duas ou s[o uma? Se uma, qual delas? E insisto: pode colocar na pergunta o JS que já tentou fazer? Assim ficará mais fácil identificar onde está com dificuldade.

Comment: Eu particularmente estou confuso, mas as duas tags são `a` a de excluir e a de alterar se clicar em excluir quer ocultar ambas? este menu está em uma linha? ou seja possui vários menus deste em uma página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código deve fazer o que você está querendo, ele vai esconder todas as tags `a` da página.

```
const esconder = function(excluir) {
    if (excluir === 1){
        let a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }  
    }
};
```

Lembrando que você precisa definir de onde vem esse `excluir`